# Testing session.cookie_httponly .htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I have been trying to confirm which browsers will accept session.cookie_httponly but for my test each browser I am using fails. Which more than likely indicates my test is not correct. What I am wanting to do is test whether or not JavaScript has access to the session cookie (cookies in general). To do this I have first set the following inside my `.htaccess`

```
php_value session.cookie_httponly 1
```

I then open my browser and attempt the following in JavaScript:

```
document.cookie = 'test';
alert(document.cookie);
```

If I do not receive a blank alert or an error to console I would consider that a failed test. How do I need to be setting this up in `.htaccess` and how should I be testing for effectiveness?

Comment: Your “test” makes little sense. The PHP option affects the cookie containing the session ID only. What would an arbitrary cookie named `test` have to do with that (assuming that is not your actual session name)? And _setting_ a cookie on the client side, is not affected by this to begin with - this is only about cookies that were set via HTTP, and whether those can be _accessed_ by client-side JS or not.

Comment: @misorude if my `session_name` is the php defualt, how could I test that javascript indeed does not have access to the session cookie?

Comment: You would check if `document.cookie` contains a cookie with that name.